# Declined flag on low-quality question

Tags: support

My [last flag was declined](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/130645). I flagged and downvoted [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/255171/what-is-the-pattern) because it just doesn't contain enough information. Specifically, it's missing what level it's on and attempts made by the OP.

There are numerous questions about [think-different](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/think-different) that don't put the level information in the question (nor is it in the answer) which I feels limits the amount of views a question might get. In order for that question to be found through your favourite search engine, someone would need to copy+paste the puzzle, as opposed to someone writing "solve think different level 10" (I'm guessing, I don't know what level it is).

Arguably these things aren't needed, but it would help search results, and would certainly be a *better* question (i.e. more researched) if the OP lists several things they thought of (being a *bad* question doesn't make it off-topic though)

Was my flag correctly declined? How should have I handled this situation, and how should I handle it in the future where the questions lacks (imo) important details. I'm far more accustomed to Stack Overflow, where "i has problem give me the code" questions **are** off-topic, but is this kind of question on-topic here? e.g.

> 3, 4, 5, x, 7
>   what's the answer?

<sub>(since the question is tagged [think-different](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/think-different) it's not necessarily to mention the game name, and mentioning "I tried several things" doesn't mean anything)</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question isn't awesome, but it is clear what they are asking - they want to know what the pattern is. Knowing what they tried isn't necessarily useful here, nor is necessarily knowing the level. These things are helpful, sure, but the core of the question is there and answerable.

This is one of those simple games where there's not a lot of detail to be added - some games need more detail to be able to help, others don't.

In general, unclear what you are asking should be used when you literally don't know what they are asking or what kind of problem they're trying to solve. In this case, the question wasn't stellar, but it was clear enough.